# Renaming multiple rasters with ModelBuilder gives errors 000622 and 000878?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, raster-calculator, error-000622

I have 101 raster images stacked inside a folder. The Rasters are of arcinfo grid type (*.asc) while having  a long string name 'NW2D_T100_05_base_depthXXX.asc' where XXX ranges from  000 to 100. What I would like to do is to add each of them with a single DTM. I tried to use ArcGIS 10.1 model builder by inserting raster iterators and raster calculator tool and the model looks as follows:

[image]

When I ran the model, the following error message was displayed:

[image]

The error numbers are 000622 and 000878.

It looks like that I have a very long string name for each raster data. How can I rename the raster with the 8 digits of the name (i.e., depthXXX.asc) for each file ? And how can I save 101 new rasters in  anew directory.

Comment: Is there any way , so that , using only modelbuilder, I can renaem the rasters first and then perform raster calculation?

Comment: I'm deleting my earlier comment because I had overlooked a detail that you had already provided. The renaming should be possible but I do not have time to look at now so will leave for someone else to Answer.

Comment: Could you clarify "What I would like to do is to add each of them with a single DTM"?  What operation are you performing with the raster calculator?

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates your output raster name is too long. I have found tiff files to support long file names so you need your raster output file name to be NW2D_T100_05_base_depthXXX.**tif**

Alternatively you could write the rasters into a file geodatabase which supports long raster names.